# Couchbase rebalancing mismatch

Tags: couchbase

I´ve been having a problem after configure my cluster, using cuchbase Rest API, when I want to add new nodes, and then rebalancing.

Here what I´m doing

Create account and cluster for machine A

```
createAccount(){
    ip=$1
    curl -s -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -X POST http://${ip}:8091/pools/default -d memoryQuota=${QUOTA} }

createCluster(){
    ip=$1
    # Initialize Node
    curl  -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -v -X POST http://${ip}:8091/nodes/self/controller/settings \
      -d 'data_path=%2Fopt%2Fcouchbase%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fcouchbase%2Fdata& \
      index_path=%2Fopt%2Fcouchbase%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fcouchbase%2Fdata'

    # Rename Node
    curl  -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -v -X POST http://${ip}:8091/node/controller/rename \
      -d 'hostname=127.0.0.1'

    # Setup Services
    curl  -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -v -X POST http://${ip}:8091/node/controller/setupServices \
      -d 'services=kv%2Cn1ql%2Cindex'

    # Setup Administrator username and password
    curl  -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -v -X POST http://${ip}:8091/settings/web \
      -d "password=$PASSWORD&username=$USER&port=SAME"

}
```

Create account and cluster for machine B (The same script than above)

Then add server B calling server A

```
addServer(){
    curl -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} http://A:8091/controller/addNode \
          -d "hostname=B&user=$USER&password=$PASSWORD&services=kv%2Cn1ql%2Cindex"

}
```

Then I can see how in A and B server I have B as pending to rebalancing.
But when I try to rebalance calling A

```
rebalance(){
    masterIp=$1
    couchbaseNode=$2
    curl -v  -u ${USER}:${PASSWORD} -X POST http://A:8091/controller/rebalance \
    -d "knownNodes=ns_1@A, ns_1@B"
 }
```

Server returns

```
  {"mismatch":1}
```

What I´m doing wrong here?

Regards

EDIT:

This is the stack of HTTP to give extra information

First machine

```
----- CREATING COUCHBASE CLUSTER ON 172.31.35.67
*   Trying 172.31.35.67...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.35.67 (172.31.35.67) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /nodes/self/controller/settings HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.35.67:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 129
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [129 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 129 out of 129 bytes

100   129    0     0  100   129      0    107  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   107< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:27:59 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 

100   129    0     0  100   129      0     79  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    80
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.35.67 left intact
*   Trying 172.31.35.67...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.35.67 (172.31.35.67) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /node/controller/rename HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.35.67:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 18
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [18 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 18 out of 18 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:27:59 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 

100    18    0     0  100    18      0   5253 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6000
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.35.67 left intact
*   Trying 172.31.35.67...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.35.67 (172.31.35.67) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /node/controller/setupServices HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.35.67:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 26
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [26 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 26 out of 26 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:27:59 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 

100    26    0     0  100    26      0   3992 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4333
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.35.67 left intact
*   Trying 172.31.35.67...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.35.67 (172.31.35.67) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /settings/web HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.35.67:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 50
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [50 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:27:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 42
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 
{ [42 bytes data]
```

Second machine

```
   Trying 172.31.134.213...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.134.213 (172.31.134.213) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /nodes/self/controller/settings HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.134.213:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 129
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [129 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 129 out of 129 bytes
100   129    0     0  100   129      0    107  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   107< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:34:03 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 

100   129    0     0  100   129      0     81  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    81
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.134.213 left intact
*   Trying 172.31.134.213...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.134.213 (172.31.134.213) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /node/controller/rename HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.134.213:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 18
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [18 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 18 out of 18 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:34:03 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 

100    18    0     0  100    18      0   1976 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2000
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.134.213 left intact
*   Trying 172.31.134.213...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.134.213 (172.31.134.213) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /node/controller/setupServices HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.134.213:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 26
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [26 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 26 out of 26 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:34:03 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 

100    26    0     0  100    26      0   9626 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 13000
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.134.213 left intact
*   Trying 172.31.134.213...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.134.213 (172.31.134.213) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /settings/web HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.134.213:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 50
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [50 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:34:03 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 44
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 
{ [44 bytes data]

100    94  100    44  100    50  15422  17525 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25000
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.134.213 left intact
{"newBaseUri":"http://172.31.134.213:8091/"}----- ADD NODE 172.31.134.213 IN COUCHBASE CLUSTER 172.31.35.67
masterID:172.31.35.67
node:172.31.134.213
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    87    0     0  100    87      0  55769 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 43500
 32   268    0     0  100    87      0     81  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    81
100   268  100   181  100    87    169     81  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   169
["Join completion call failed. Got HTTP status 500 from REST call post to http://172.31.134.213:8091/completeJoin. Body was: \"[\\\"Unexpected server error, request logged.\\\"]\""]----- REBALANCING NODE 172.31.134.213 IN COUCHBASE CLUSTER 172.31.35.67
*   Trying 172.31.35.67...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.31.35.67 (172.31.35.67) port 8091 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'Administrator'
> POST /controller/rebalance HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwb2xpdHJvbg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: 172.31.35.67:8091
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 30
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [30 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 30 out of 30 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Couchbase Server
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 09:34:04 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 14
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< 
{ [14 bytes data]

100    44  100    14  100    30  11965  25641 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 30000
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.35.67 left intact
{"mismatch":1}
```

As you can see the last request fail with a 400 code

Comment: Can you show the raw http request and response? This might help figure out what in the call is the wrong info being passed in. Also, this has nothing to do with CouchDB, so you should remove that tag.

Comment: @Kirk I just add the details of http request-response, why do you think is not couchbase related?

Comment: The reason I say it is not CouchDB related is that CouchDB and Couchbase are two separate products. I do not see a reason why your call should not work. What version of Couchbase are you running so I can try and replicate the problem.

Comment: @Kirk version 4.0. I´ll remove CouchDB, thanks

Comment: ok. I''ll go back and find that version and test it. full disclosure, it might not be until tomorrow, sorry. I have no idea if it will fix it, but just know that for Community version it is on 4.1 and Enterprise (paid) is on 4.5.

Comment: 4.1 is the version. Thanks for all your time on this

Answer (score 1):

In the knownNodes list, remove the spaces between the nodes. I was able to replicate it. With the spaces, {"mismatch":1}. Without the spaces, it works.

I have opened a bug on the documentation on this issue.